# Telling the vote?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

English is my second language.

I heard someone saying "Now that the right people are telling the vote..."

I wrote down 'telling' but I don't think it was that word.

What could that verb be that could sound like 'telling' to mean "...now that the right people are voting..."?

I'm pretty sure it wasn't "casting".

Situation is like in the 'survival' show. There are two teams and the loser team was to pick someone to leave. That line is said before they are going into the area to pick each one's 'worst performer' choice.

Comment: Perhaps [tallying](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tally)?

Comment: Thanks. Yes I just found about that word.. I'm now pretty sure it was that word... but what confuses me now.. is that.. can that word be used to mean ..start voting? Because that line was said before everyone is going to the area to vote someone to leave

Comment: Dear mega, native speaker or not, a double period is not a punctuation mark in English (or any language I am aware of, for that matter). Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether OP's intended sense is *casting* or *counting* here. But given the recent furore over supposedly excessive downvoting, I'm voting to reopen now, in the pious hope that @mega will edit to clarify that point for us.

Answer (score 5):

One of the meanings of *tell* is ‘count’ in the context of voting. In the UK’s Houses of Parliament, the ‘tellers’ are those who count the vote after the members have voted on a motion. So your example is quite feasible, but without seeing the wider context it is hard to be sure.

Comment: And assistants behind the counters in banks are called *tellers* for the same reason: they count money.